# Where can I buy postage stamps in Manila, Philippines? And where can I go to send postcards? How much will it be?

Tags: usa, price, philippines, mail, manila

Where can I buy a postage stamp near Paco, Manila, Philippines? What stamps will I need to send it to the US?

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close this as 'price-shopping' - I don't think OP is asking for a specific shop to go to, but rather the general gist of how sending a postcard works in the Philippines. What type of stamp is needed for a postcard seems a perfectly reasonable travel question, and asking what it will cost isn't the same thing as price-shopping.

Comment: and yes, "how do I send a postcard?" might *sound* obvious, but it's certainly something that can be extremely unintuitive for non-locals in some places. My wife and I were baffled in Barcelona when trying to get stamps. Eventually we asked somebody and discovered that if you want a stamp, you should head for your nearest tobacconist. *Well obviously, why didn't we think of that?*

Comment: @ChrisH They don't specify where they want to send it to meaning it's too broad

Comment: @Daniil yes they do. "How can I send the postcards to US?"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use The Philippine's official postal service.

I looked up [all their post offices](https://www.phlpost.gov.ph/post-office-location.php) in Manila and this was the closes to Paco:

> Municipality : 2F Robinson's Otis, UN Avenue, Manila
> Address : Robinson's Otis

The [cost of a postcard](https://www.phlpost.gov.ph/assets/files/FINAL%20RATES.pdf) to send to the USA is:

- up to 20 grams: 24.00 ₱
- 21-50 grams: 58.00 ₱
- 51-100 grams: 80.00 ₱
- 101-250 grams: 147.00 ₱
- 251-500 grams: 258.00 ₱
- 501-1000 grams: 481.00 ₱
- Add-on per 500 grams after 100 grams: 258.00 ₱

Comment: Those seem to be the prices for "International Express Mail Service (Documents)". I'm no expert on the mail service of the Philippines, but I'd imagine that the "international ordinary mail service" would be a much more likely choice for sending a postcard. Prices for that service start at (and for a regular postcard won't go above) just 55 pesos, rather than the 1460 pesos (~25EUR) you've quoted here.

Comment: @ChrisH Ah, so SAL mail?

Comment: I was suggesting "international ordinary mail service", labelled as that on page 8 of the pdf you linked to, but actually yes the "Surface air lifted" option appears to be cheaper. Although I may be misunderstanding something, it seems very strange that sending books would be significantly cheaper (~2/3) than sending a letter in the same weight class.

Comment: @ChrisH Agreed, I updated the answer for letter costs